# Joomla 2.5 new registered user php script with dbl opt-in java

Tags: php, api, acl, joomla1.7

I've created a simple "create an account" form in html that is tied to interspire with some java for a double opt-in method.  I would also like this form to create the user in Joomla and log them in after clicking the create account button.

The double opt-in works fine but the new user script for joomla 2.5 isn't working, no errors but it just doesn't register the user.  I've tried placing the php script (see below) found on stackoverflow to generate a new user but it's not working.

Is it possible to run these two types of scripts together on one form?  If so, where am I going wrong?  Thanks!

```
 require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

//Check for request forgeries, we comment this out since tokens are not generated in the html page
//JRequest::checkToken() or jexit( 'Invalid Token' );

//Get required system objects

$user         = clone(JFactory::getUser());
$pathway          = & $mainframe->getPathway();
$config       = & JFactory::getConfig();
$authorize        = & JFactory::getACL();
$document       = & JFactory::getDocument();

//If user registration is not allowed, show 403 not authorized(Not needed)

$usersConfig = &JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_users' );
if ($usersConfig->get('allowUserRegistration') == '0')
    {
        JError::raiseError( 403, JText::_( 'Access Forbidden' ));
        return;
    }

//Initialize new usertype setting

$newUsertype = $usersConfig->get( 'new_usertype' );
if (!$newUsertype)
    {
        $newUsertype = 'Registered';
    }

//Bind the post array to the user object
if (!$user->bind( JRequest::get('post'), 'usertype' ))
    {
        JError::raiseError( 500, $user->getError());
    }

//Set some initial user values

$user->set('id', 0);
$user->set('usertype', '');
$user->set('gid', $authorize->get_group_id( '', $newUsertype, 'ARO' ));

$date =& JFactory::getDate();
$user->set('registerDate', $date->toMySQL());

//If user activation is turned on, we need to set the activation information(Not needed)

$useractivation = $usersConfig->get( 'useractivation' );
if ($useractivation == '1')
    {
        jimport('joomla.user.helper');
        $user->set('activation', md5( JUserHelper::genRandomPassword()) );
        $user->set('block', '1');
    }

//Save the details of the user

$user->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to create an API to register a user in Joomla from different environment. Your code will work fine with Joomla 1.5/1.6, but not with 1.7 onwards... The below snippet worked for me, slightly modified one.

```
<?php
/*
 * Created on 13-Apr-12
 *
 * To change the template for this generated file go to
 * Window - Preferences - PHPeclipse - PHP - Code Templates
 */
 /*
  * loading Joomla environment
  */
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
$JUnit_home = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
//define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root


define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

function register_user ($email, $password){

$firstname = $email; // generate $firstname
$lastname = ''; // generate $lastname
$username = $email; // username is the same as email


/*
I handle this code as if it is a snippet of a method or function!!

First set up some variables/objects     */


//$acl =& JFactory::getACL(); Acl will work only in Joomla1.5/1.6       

/* get the com_user params */
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$usersParams = &JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_users' ); // load the Params

// "generate" a new JUser Object
$user = JFactory::getUser(0); // it's important to set the "0" otherwise your admin user information will be loaded

$data = array(); // array for all user settings


//original logic of name creation
//$data['name'] = $firstname.' '.$lastname; // add first- and lastname
$data['name'] = $firstname.$lastname; // add first- and lastname

$data['username'] = $username; // add username
$data['email'] = $email; // add email
//there's no gid field in #__users table from Joomla_1.7/2.5

$usertype = 'Registered';//this is not necessary!!!
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');
/* this part of the snippet from here: /plugins/user/joomla/joomla.php*/
$config = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users');
    // Default to Registered.
$defaultUserGroup = $config->get('new_usertype', 2);
//default to defaultUserGroup i.e.,Registered
$data['groups']=array($defaultUserGroup);
$data['password'] = $password; // set the password
$data['password2'] = $password; // confirm the password
$data['sendEmail'] = 1; // should the user receive system mails?

/* Now we can decide, if the user will need an activation */

 $useractivation = $usersParams->get( 'useractivation' ); // in this example, we load the config-setting
 //echo $useractivation;exit();
 if ($useractivation == 1) { // yeah we want an activation

 jimport('joomla.user.helper'); // include libraries/user/helper.php
 $data['block'] = 1; // block the User
 $data['activation'] =JUtility::getHash( JUserHelper::genRandomPassword() ); // set activation hash (don't forget to send an activation email)

}
else { // no we need no activation

 $data['block'] = 1; // don't block the user

}

if (!$user->bind($data)) { // now bind the data to the JUser Object, if it not works....
 JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError())); // ...raise an Warning
    return false; // if you're in a method/function return false

}

if (!$user->save()) { // if the user is NOT saved...
 JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError())); // ...raise an Warning

 return false; // if you're in a method/function return false

}

return $user; // else return the new JUser object

}

$email = JRequest::getVar('email');
$password = JRequest::getVar('password');

//echo 'User registration...'.'<br/>';
if(!register_user($email, $password))
{
$data['status']="failure";
echo json_encode($data);
}
else
{
$data['status']="success";
echo json_encode($data);
}
 //echo '<br/>'.'User registration is completed'.'<br/>';
?>
```

> P.S. Please check #_*users(user details), #*_book_user_usergroup_map(maps group id and user id), #__usergroups table holds Group keys tables being affected after registration

Comment: A small fix, the else "don't block the user" should be $data['block'] = 0

Comment: "set activation hash (don't forget to send an activation email)"
**How do you do send an activation email in code?**